# Express application as a IIS subsite fails to load static files

Tags: angular, express, iis, angular-universal

I'm setting up an Angular Universal application with Express in IIS, with a reverse proxy as described in this  article https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b. If i set my IIS site up as http://example.com with a rewrite url to http://localhost:4000/{R:1} (node application is listening on 4000) everything is working fine.

I would like to use a subsite in IIS, for example http://example/abc, so I set up an application under my website called abc which has the abovementioned rewrite rule. Now when I browse to http://example.com/abc the browser is trying to load js/css files from http://example.com, which leads to 404 errors. Am I doing something wrong? I've set up Angular sites as subsites in IIS previously (not Universal), which correctly loads js/css files.

Comment: Does your angular app use a `"baseHref": "/abc"`?

Comment: disable the reverse proxy rule and try to just browse the hosted node express application.and do you want to host just simple node js application or node js express application in iis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `--deploy-url` option when doing a build

```
ng build --prod --deploy-url /abc
```